# batch copy and rename files in virtual path

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to copy multiple files from different sources to virtual path on domain

My code is:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
net use X: /delete

net use X: \\192.168.11.240\my virual path name

set folderpath="X:\"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "source1\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a
XCOPY /Y  "source1\%Youngest%" "%folderpath%"


for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "source2\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a
XCOPY /Y "source2\%Youngest%" "%folderpath%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "source3\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a
XCOPY /Y "source3\%Youngest%" "%folderpath%"
@echo on

cd %folderpath%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%folderpath%\*.txt"') do (
   set "fname=%%~na"
   ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"

)

pause
```

I am getting the error msg:

> "batch file error the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Stephan: I did not change the code in any way.

Comment: @Stephan: look at the actual markdown, not the rendered output (use the `side-by-side markdown` button to see that). Two backslashes are rendered as a single backslash when the text is not formatted as code. When applying the code formatting the two backlashes are displayed (but they have been in the code from the beginning)

Comment: `@a_horse_with_no_name Uh? wtf - Confusing... you are right. Let's delete this conversation.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0):

> you should use double quotation marks if there is any space in path.

Try to Map drive with this:

```
net use X: /delete
net use X: "\\192.168.11.240\my virual path name" /persistent:yes
```

Comment: still not working...seems like it's not recognize the X:\ path after cd X:\

Comment: use `cd /d x:\` to switch to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use `pushd` for this, I guess.

It basically does the same as `net use` does and automatically changes the directory. That might help already (and then use `popd` when you are finished with the task).

Further you could put in `pause` to see where exactly the error happens (meaning in which of the blocks you wrote).

In the first two For-Loops you used `%youngest%` instead of `!youngest!`; not sure if that was intended.

Lastly I am not sure how the last For-Loop works, but it looks like you first change the directory including the `\` and then let the For-Loop look for `X:\\` as you included another backslash in there.